# Create name value pairs in python

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a python script that has the following output stored in a variable called jvmData:

```
Stats name=jvmRuntimeModule, type=jvmRuntimeModule#
{
name=HeapSize, ID=1, description=The total memory (in KBytes) in the Java virtual machine run time., unit=KILOBYTE, type=BoundedRangeStatistic, lowWaterMark=1048576, highWaterMark=1048576, current=1048576, integral=0.0, lowerBound=1048576, upperBound=2097152

name=FreeMemory, ID=2, description=The free memory (in KBytes) in the Java virtual machine run time., unit=KILOBYTE, type=CountStatistic, count=348466

name=UsedMemory, ID=3, description=The amount of used memory (in KBytes) in the Java virtual machine run time., unit=KILOBYTE, type=CountStatistic, count=700109

name=UpTime, ID=4, description=The amount of time (in seconds) that the Java virtual machine has been running., unit=SECOND, type=CountStatistic, count=3706565

name=ProcessCpuUsage, ID=5, description=The CPU Usage (in percent) of the Java virtual machine., unit=N/A, type=CountStatistic, count=0
}
```

What I would like to do is simply print out name/value pairs for the important parts, which in this case would simply be:

```
HeapSize=1048576
FreeMemory=348466
UsedMemory=700109
UpTime=3706565
ProcessCpuUsage=0
```

Im not at all good with python :) The only solution in my head seems very long-winded? Split the lines, throw away first, second and last lines, then loop through each line with different cases (sometimes current, sometimes count) for finding the length of string, etc etc

Perhaps (well definitely) I am missing something some nice function I can use to put these into the equivalent of a java hashmap or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "equivalent of a java HashMap" would be called a dictionary in python. As for how to parse this, just iterate over the lines that contain the data, make a dict of all key/value pairs in the line and have a special case for the `HeapSize`:

```
jvmData = "..." #the string holding the data
jvmLines = jvmData.split("\n") #a list of the lines in the string
lines = [l.strip() for l in jvmLines if "name=" in l] #filter all data lines
result = {}
for line in lines:
    data = dict(s.split("=") for s in line.split(", "))
    #the value is in "current" for HeapSize or in "count" otherwise
    value = data["current"] if data["name"] == "HeapSize" else data["count"]
    result[data["name"]] = value
```

As you seem to be stuck on Jython2.1, here's a version that should work with it (obviously untested). Basically the same as above, but with the list comprehension and generator expression replaced by `filter` and `map` respectively, and without using the ternary `if/else` operator:

```
jvmData = "..." #the string holding the data
jvmLines = jvmData.split("\n") #a list of the lines in the string
lines = filter(lambda x: "name=" in x, jvmLines) #filter all data lines
result = {}
for line in lines:
    data = dict(map(lambda x: x.split("="), line.split(", ")))
    if data["name"] == "HeapSize":
        result[data["name"]] = data["current"]
    else:
        result[data["name"]] = data["count"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer @l4mpi <--- take note elitist downvoters! I'll have a play with it and see how far I get :)

Comment: hmm, I have the string held in a variable (not a file) called jvmData and tried to change your code accordingly. i.e. 'lines = [l.strip() for l in jvmData if "name=" in l]' but syntax errors ->  lines = lstrip()^for l in jvmData if "name=" in l

Comment: The `[]` brackets for the list comprehension are missing in your error message, you probably removed those during your change. For the list comprehension to work, you also need to split the string into the lines. See my edit for a solution that should work.

Comment: Still getting the same thing... - here is the full output (Pointer is pointing at the 'f' in 'for')

Comment: WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/tmp/test.py"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (innermost last):
  (no code object) at line 0
  File "<string>", line 28
            data = dict(s.split("=") for s in line.split(", "))
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Seer The error message suggests you're running WebSphere/wsadmin? According to the IBM documentation this uses Jython 2.1, which is an extremely outdated version of python (and jython too) released in 2001. The generator expression that gives you the syntax error was introduced in python 2.4 about 10 years ago, if you're still on 2.1 it obviously won't work - as will the ternary expression in the line after that, which was introduced in 2.5. I'll include a version that _should_ work with 2.1; but please add this information to future questions as it's rather important.

Comment: Wow! Is it so old??!! This is WAS8.5.5 too (their very latest release!) Sorry for causing the extra issues, I just expected it to be a 'relatively' recent version in the very latest release :) I'll give it a try and let you know. Many thanks for your persistence :)

Comment: @Seer The quote from the documentation about jython2.1 was for WAS6, but it seems it's still valid for 8.5 (you can find the exact python version you're using in `sys.version` and `sys.version_info`). At least you can in theory update it, I've found [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1207_vansickel/1207_vansickel.html) describing the process - seems to be a bit of work, but if you're doing a lot of scripting it's probably worth upgrading to jython 2.5.3 which is the current stable release.

Comment: huh? Now it gives- Exception running command: "jvmLines = jvmData.split("\n")"; AttributeError: split. Does it not consider the variable a string?

Comment: @Seer it seems to be something else than a string. Printing `type(jvmData)` should let you find out what it is...

Comment: <jclass org.python.core.PyJavaInstance at -332784633> so its some java object right? tried the following test=jvmData.toString
wsadmin>print test
<method com.ibm.ws.pmi.stat.StatsImpl.toString of com.ibm.ws.pmi.stat.StatsImpl instance at -109136963>

Comment: @Seer you should probably _call_ the `toString` method, as in `test = jvmData.toString()`. Alternatively, you could try calling `str(jvmData)`. I don't think debugging this remotely and one exception at a time makes much sense though...

Comment: I agree - sorry this turned out into an extended chat session. str(jvmData) works and I will work out the rest myself. Just wanted to say I really appreciate the help, and its guys like you that make this site tick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something using find function and small re:

```
import re
final_map = {}
NAME= 'name='
COUNT= 'count='
HIGHWATERMARK= "highWaterMark="
def main():    
    with open(r'<file_location>','r') as file:
        lines = [line for line in file if re.search(r'^name', line)]        
        for line in lines:                    
            sub = COUNT if line.find(COUNT) != -1  else HIGHWATERMARK       
            final_map[line[line.find(NAME)+5:line.find(',')]] = line[line.find(sub)+len(sub):].split(',')[0].strip()
            print line[line.find(NAME)+5:line.find(',')]+'='+final_map[line[line.find(NAME)+5:line.find(',')]]                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
HeapSize=1048576
FreeMemory=348466
UsedMemory=700109
UpTime=3706565
ProcessCpuUsage=0
```

Comment: Thats what I love about this place - one question and different approaches come back all looking equally good :) I'll try your method too and I'll update the question to specify I have the data in a variable and not a file

Comment: Downvote. In my opinion regex isn't the best tool to solve this, but this code is a particularily bad example. You're needlessly using `re.search` instead of the `in` operator in your list comprehension; even worse, you're fetching the values by slicing on the `find` result plus the string length, which is counterintuitive and prone to breaking (replace the search string and forget to change the int, you'll silently get wrong results) - `re.match` with capture groups would have been better. But why use `re` at all when you can turn the whole line into a dict with a simple `split`?

Comment: @l4mpi : Since you had already presented the dict way. I thought of writing it in a different way. Meanwhile he had not specified that the values were in variable when i wrote the code at the first place. And find in slicing works perfectly fine as long as the file is static. Searching specific things is more efficient then loading everything in the map, like in your case, which would be really troublesome if the input size keeps growing.

Comment: Well, feel free to propose an alternative solution, but please do so in a way that doesn't promote bad practices. Seriously, the way you get the names and values in your code is just bad. The worst example is the `highWaterMark` line, where you calculate `line[line.find('highWaterMark=')+14:][:line[line.find('highWaterMark=')+14:].find(',')].strip()` which fails in just about every aspect I can imagine. For starters, you can express it as `line.split("highWaterMark=")[1].split(",")[0]`. Using `split` or `re.match` _could_ be an alternative to my solution, your current code certainly isn't one.

Comment: Slicing is always more efficient then splitting. Why would that be prone to error, and how on earth is slicing a bad practice? I understand what you propose is a small solution, but that is definitely not the best in terms of memory management. Split will create two immutable string memory blocks, whereas slice is just an pointer/reference to already available integer to the 256 integer register.

Comment: Not slicing in general, your usage of it. The code is neither readable nor easily changeable (you'd have to edit __4__ places in this line to get the `current` value instead of `highWaterMark` - forget one and you'll get a wrong result), and it's not efficient at all as you're using three slices and three calls to find (which could be reduced to two each if you introduced an extra variable). But optimization would be extremely premature anyways, OP has only a few KB of data and has put no emphasis on speed or ram usage; also I'm sure I could trivially optimize my solution for larger input.

Comment: Lets not go into readability and places of changing, I have already mentioned that your way was good, and I was trying to propose an alternative solution since you had already used the dict method.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm just telling you why I downvoted and think your solution is bad - I doubt I'm alone with this opinion, you could ask around in the StackOverflow python chatroom and people would probably tell you the same things I've just told you (and I don't write this comments to piss you off either, it's just honest advice). Also, while readability might not be of importance for personal scripts, for SO where _everything_ you write is for somebody else, it's usually extremely important as you want the asker to learn and understand what your code does, so they can help themselves next time.

Comment: Vivek - Thanks first of all for taking the time to answer, and I did play with it and got something working. But at the same time its not so flexible. For instance I will probably be adding more metrics to the script and they of course have different patterns and this code has to be low maintenance for colleagues who are even less knowledgable than me!